# TypeScript: How to infer the type of one generic based on another generic?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I have this code:

```
class A<T> {
    a(t: T) {
        console.log(t);
    }
}

class B<T, O extends {b: T}> {
    constructor(public a: A<O>) {
    }

    b(t: T) {
        console.log(t)
    }
}

const a = new A<{b: number}>(); // type: A<{ b: number; }>

const b = new B(a); // type: B<unknown, { b: number; }>
```

Why does the TypeScript mark argument of the method `b` of the class `B` as unknown?

Comment: Is your editor showing you some message indicating a problem? Could you add a screenshot, or copy the error text?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=6&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGt6YAUALgFzSICU6WO1wA9gHYS0gCmAdCLQOaFkDcVbAF8MIjKEgwAQkgA00APLQWADwIt6AExhoARiURDUmGgwgEATgFdgBWhbwAHK7pABLYLhIIFyCiZwxal1CA39Bamg6RmZ2Th4CMgiRMWjzXGgAXmh6FgB3OHg9EnorAFtdFgsjPH5xMwJoXSyc-OgpPDA63TZdIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have types `T` and `O` where `O extends {b: T}`.  The relationship between `T` and `O['b']` is that `O['b'] extends T`.  This means that `T` could be `O['b']` exactly but it also could be any type that is ***broader*** than `O['b']`.

This direction of inference is impossible for typescript to infer because there are infinitely many types for `T` such that `number extends T`.  You could have a very broad type like `any` or `{}` as suggested by @md2perpe.  You could have a union that includes `number` like `string | number`, etc.

In order to be able to infer the second parameter, we need the `extends` to go the other way.  We need to know that `T` must be ***narrower*** than `O['b']`.  We can write that like this:

```
class B<T extends O['b'], O extends {b: any}> {
```

Here we say that `O` is some object with a `b` property.  We say that `T` is some type which is either the `b` value of `O` or a subset of it.  Now typescript will infer `T` as `O['b']`.

```
const a = new A<{b: number}>(); // type: A< b: number; }>

const b = new B(a); // type: B<number, { b: number; }>

b.b(5) // takes type: number
```

Note that you can still manually set `T` to a narrower type:

```
const specificB = new B<5, {b: number}>(a); // type: B<5, { b: number; }>

specificB.b(10); // error: Argument of type '10' is not assignable to parameter of type '5'.
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/N9AyoN)

Answer (score 2):

Do you think that it should derive that `T = number`? If the condition were `O equals { b: T }` (which you can't write), then that would be true. But since `number extends {}` we can as well have `T = {}`.

In this code, `g` will have type `true`:

```
type G<T> = { b: number } extends { b: T } ? true : false;
let g: G<{}>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what the problem is here. The class `B` has two generic type parameters `T` and `O`. The constructor for `B` only accepts a parameter of type `A<O>`, but no parameters of type `T`. So when you create a new `B` there is no way to tell what `T` should be bound to. Try `new B<Type1, Type2>(a)` to help the compiler.

Comment: In my experience, the first generic type should be inferred from the second generic type.